# How git handle renamed file when merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

Can anyone describe how git handle renamed file when merge?

I am facing a problem when merge renamed file commit.

For ex:
**in master**
commit 1 : add b.txt

my master folder view:

```
b.txt
```

**in feature**
commit 1 : add b.txt `this is not the same commit, just same change`
commit 2 : move b.txt to myfolder/b.txt `it show renamed file in git ui`

my feature folder view:

```
myfolder/b.txt
```

When I in master, I do

```
git merge feature
```

I thought I can get this:
my master folder view after merge:

```
myfolder/b.txt
```

But git doesn't delete b.txt, instead my master final result:

```
b.txt  
myfolder/b.txt
```

I can't figure out why, isn't my commit 2 in feature branch already delete the b.txt? Why it still in my merged master.

By the way, if I just cherry pick the commit 2 in feature branch, it work well(delete the b.txt).But it doesn't looks like a correct way to merge a branch.

**update:**
By the way2, if I use rebase instead merge, it will give me the "right" result.

Comment: Well, like you pointed out yourself, the b.txt added in the feature branch is a different file (not the same commit), so I think it's only natural that the both files exist after the merge. If you had left out commit 2 in your feature branch, there would have been a conflict due to two files having the same file path.

Comment: Btw, the git repository doesn't track renames, it gets recorded as delete + add. The reason you can see "rename" status in various places is because the client is clever enough to figure this out for you. See the last section of https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository for more info

Comment: If I left out commit 2 in my feature, it still merge successful without any conflict popup.this is why I think git know the two b.txt are same file(even it's add by different commit/branch).And this is why I don't know why git didn't delete the b.txt for me.

Comment: @user1686407 - No, git doesn't "know" they're the same; at least not in the way you're thinking.  When it attempts the merge without the 2nd commit, it does detect the two creations of `b.txt` as a conflict, but it then notices that the change on both sides of the conflict is identical, so it auto-resolves it rather than make you do a manual resolution.  But that *only* happens because it's analyzing the conflict, which it won't do when you include the 2nd commit (because then there is no conflict among the 3 versions actually involved in the merge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments do point out some of the nuances of dealing with renames in git, but they don't really address the reason for what you're seeing.

When git does a merge, it *does not* look at branches' commits individually.  Instead it looks at three things:  The merge base (the most recent common ancestor, roughly); "our" commit (the tip of the branch in to which you are merging); and "their" commit (the tip of the branch you're merging in).

It compares "base" to "ours" to determine "our changes", and it sees that you created `b.txt`.  It compares "base" to "theirs" to determine "their changes", and this is where things aren't as you hoped.  Because it doesn't look at the intermediate states, it does not know that you created `b.txt` and then moved it to `myfolder/b.txt`; it only knows that over the course of the branch, `myfolder/b.txt` was created.

So the union of the changes is "create `b.txt` and create `myfolder/b.txt`", and there is no conflict in that, so it just does both.

The interesting thing is, while `merge` and `rebase` *usually* produce the same result, and are thought of as differing only in the history they produce, this is a very rare case in which rebase, because it *does* look at each commit's changes individually, can produce a more intuitive result.

Comment: yes, rebase give me more intuitive result, I update my question, include rebase stuff.

Comment: ok, so I should use rebase whenever I need "merge"? looks like compare mechanism may give me unexpected result.

Comment: @user1686407 - That is not my recommendation. What you've described is an edge case in which a 3-way merge doesn't behave as expected, but it rarely comes up and it is easily fixed if it does come up. There are more important issues than this when deciding whether you want to use rebase or merge. If others share the repo, you likely need to consider the disruptive effect of history rewrites.  You need to consider whether it's ok to have intermediate merges that do not compile and/or pass any automated tests you might have.  And you need to consider what you want history to look like.

Comment: @user1686407 - Also, note that (1) as I said, merge and rebase usually generate the same result, and (2) when they don't, there will be some cases where the merge result is better and some cases where the rebase result is better.  It just so happens that the first one you stumbled on, you like the rebase result better.